# How to make sure OnAfterRender() gets executed after OnInitializedAsync() in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

There is again some problem that I have run into.

I have two methods in my Razor file @code block.

```
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
```

and

```
    protected override async Task OnAfterRender()
```

I want OnAfterRender() to execute only after OnInitializedAsync() has finished executing. I have looked for everywhere on how to get it worked out but this doesn't seem to be discussed anywhere. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: simply using a couple of bool flags perhaps?

Comment: Maybe you could use OnInitialized() instead of OnInitializedAsync()?

Comment: @IMil I have something I am returning, can't do it with OnInitialized().

Comment: Don't you forgot to await something. The framework should handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm realy surprise that's not already handled by the framework. Don't you forget to await somethings wiht the `await` key word?

Any way, when I have to sychronize thread I use a [WaitHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle?view=netcore-3.0)

Your code could be :

```cs
private ManuelResetEvent _syncEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await awaitableStuff();
    _syncEvent.Set();
}

protected override async Task OnAfterRender()
{
    _syncEvent.WaitOne();
    await otherAwaitableStuff();
}
```

Don't forget to dispose the `WaitHandle`.